# curl issue getting data from website

Tags: curl

I'm using this code to get name and phone from website `pj.ma/pagesjaunes` but it give an error when executing can you help please ?

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.pj.ma/pagesjaunes");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "pro_quiquoi=britel&pro_ou=casablanca&x=85&y=35");

    $output=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: "it give an error", please elaborate with more details.

Comment: hello thanks for your answer , the expected reply is the name and phone number of the person requested but here it just give an error saying that the protocol used is not correct , you can try the script you will get the error